# Overwrite elements in array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to update an element in an array.
Importing the data using `Invoke-WebMethod` works fine:

```
$service = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $URL -Credential $cred | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I want to update `$service.service.statechangetimesec`:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $service.service.statechangetimesec
Sun Mar 19 14:29:17 2017
Sun Mar 19 14:29:20 2017
Sun Mar 19 12:27:46 2017
Sun Mar 19 12:27:46 2017
```

to look like:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $service.service.statechangetimesec
Sun Mar 19 14:29:17 2017 (GMT)
Sun Mar 19 14:29:20 2017 (GMT)
Sun Mar 19 12:27:46 2017 (GMT)
Sun Mar 19 12:27:46 2017 (GMT)
```

I can do the following `$service.service | ForEach-Object {$_.statechangetimesec + (" GMT") }`

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $service.service | ForEach-Object {$_.statechangetimesec + (" GMT") }
Sun Mar 19 14:29:17 2017 (GMT)
Sun Mar 19 14:29:20 2017 (GMT)
Sun Mar 19 12:27:46 2017 (GMT)
Sun Mar 19 12:27:46 2017 (GMT)
```

But I just cant set the new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign them:

```
$service.service | ForEach-Object {$_.statechangetimesec = $_.statechangetimesec + (" GMT") }
```

This won't output anything but you can see the result using:

```
$service.service.statechangetimesec
```

Comment: Thanks. your answer worked. I tried other combinations of this. Why wouldn't this work `$service | ForEach-Object {"$_.service.statechangetimesec" = $_.service.statechangetimesec + (" GMT") }`

Comment: Because using the quotes you are creating a string and try to assign something to it.

Comment: My bad, I meant without the quotes... That was something I just tried! this didn't work either  `$service | ForEach-Object {$_.service.statechangetimesec = $_.service.statechangetimesec + (" GMT") }`

Comment: That doesn't work because you are iterating over the services so there is no service property....